# Compare CheckboxList's selected value with CSV string

Tags: jquery, string, csv, compare, checkboxlist

I have a list with checkboxes on a page. Whenever an item is selected it should be compared with a `CSV` string, stored in a hidden input field. The string looks likes 13,14,19`.

I need to show an alert box if the value of the selected checkbox matches with any of value that exists in my `CSV` string.

My js function is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=chkboxListReportReq.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%=chkboxListReportReq.ClientID %> input:checked').each(function () {
                    alert($(this).closest('span').attr('data-value'));
                    //alert($(this).next('label').text());
                });
            });
        });
```

This is what I've tried so far...

Comment: Could you also add the relevant HTML source code? That would be more helpful to understand your Javascript code.

Comment: `HTML` is not necessary for this question, I'm just searching for comparing a `CSV` with a string only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTML is not necessary for this question, I'm just searching for
>   comparing a CSV with a string only..

Based on your last comment there exsist more than one way. The best way is to using `search()`. Although is comes from plain Javascript, you can use it with strings stored in jquery variables.

To `search()` itself:

This method uses the Regular Expression object, as you can see like follows:

```
var myCsvfileString = "13,14,15,19";
var found = myCsvfileString.search(<place here your reg expression>);

if (found > -1) {alert("Something has been found);}
```

For an overview about the syntax of regular expressions you should look up at the Internet or here. I'm defnetly not an expert for `req expr`. The following [link](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Regular%20Expressions%20Simple%20Usage.htm#mozTocId423927) gives you some information, though I think there exists better ones.